# Scala async recursion with putting await.result inside Future

Tags: scala, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

I have this sample code below. I don't want to block inside combinator `resource.map`, so I put `Await.result` inside `Future`. But when I test this async recursion, I get `concurrent.TimeoutException` from `myRes`. What is the problem with the code? How do I fix it? Thank you.

```
// Code start here
val responses = Future.sequence(resource.map(params => asyncRecursionFunc(params)))
Await.result(responses, 5.minutes)

// My async function
def asyncRecursionFunc(params: sampleParameters, maxTryTimes: Int = 2, awaitTime: Int = 1): Future[(Seq[sample], String)] = {
    val res: Future[GraphQLCluent.GraphQLResponse[SearchQueryResponse]] = client.query("gql", params).result
    Future {
        val myRes: GraphQLCluent.GraphQLResponse[SearchQueryResponse] = Await.result(res, 2.minutes)
        val myValue: Seq[sample] = myRes.right.toSeq.flatmap(res => res) 
        if( !myValue.isEmpty || maxTryTimes <= 0 ){
            (myValue, "stringMessage")
        }
        else{
            Await.result(asyncRecursionFunc(params, maxTryTimes - 1, awaitTime + 1), (2*(awaitTime + 1)).minutes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `flatMap` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you should use `flatMap`.
`Await` is *bad* even inside a `Future` (in some way, it is actually *worse*).
It is likely what is causing your immediate problem too (first few queries exhaust all the threads in the pool, and then `Await` blocks forever).

Try doing it in a truly asynchronous way:

```
  def doQuery(params: Foo, maxTries: Int) = client.query("gql", params).result.flatMap { 
     case Right(r) if r.nonEmpty  => Future.successful(r -> "stringmessage")
     case _ if maxTries == 1 => Future.successful(Nil -> "stringmessage")
     case _ => doQuery(params, maxTries-1)
   }
```